# Javascript Switch not working as expected

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am using a switch statement to test the name attribute of a span:

```
<span id = "prompt" title = "newPerson">What is your name?</span>
<button type = "button" id = "execute">Do It!</button>
<input type="text" id="input" />


document.getElementById("execute").addEventListener("click",execute);


function execute(){
    var action = document.getElementById("prompt").title;
    var request = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if(action == "newPerson"){ alert("WTF"); }  //Alerts as expected
    this.act = function(action, request){
        switch(action){ //Default case always gets called
            case "newPerson":
                person = new Person(request, 0, 0);
                account = new Account(person);
                break;
            default:
                alert("Internal Error :(");
                break;
        }
    }
    if(request == ""){
        alert("No Input");
    }else{
        this.act();
    }
}
```

I also tried changing it to 'newPerson'. Also i tried changing my if to use '===' instead of '==' and i still got the "WTF" alert. Seems like this should be working any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy one.
When calling `this.act` you are passing no parameters - therefore the `action` parameter within you function body where the switch operator is used is `undefined` -> the default case is called.

You can basically change a function signature to the following

```
...
this.act = function(){
...
```

Then you'll produce a closure, and the `action` and `request` values will be used from the outer scope.

Or you can change this part of code, when the function is called and pass the parameters as below:

```
...
if (request == ""){
    alert("No Input");
} else {
    this.act(action, request);
}
...
```

**Note:**
Usually it is a bad pattern to have the parameters of function with the same name as variables in the outer scope - it can cause misunderstanding as in your case.

Comment: Thank you, I am surprised i didn't see that. *facepalm* I tried everything i could think of. Thanks for the suggestion, i will take it to heart.